# How To Insert record in database mysql in php html

Tags: php, html, mysql, insert

Notice: Undefined index: nama in C:\xampp\htdocs\sekolah\admin\insert.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: nis in C:\xampp\htdocs\sekolah\admin\insert.php on line 14

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "school");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$sekolah = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['sekolah']);
$nama = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['nama']);
$kelas = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['nis']);

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO sekolah (sekolah, nama, nis) VALUES ('$sekolah', '$nama', '$nis')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Is that the whole code in PHP? Does that happen when you submit, just open the page or in all cases?

Comment: which is `line 13` ? in insert.php

Comment: your form and php insert function both in same page so you have to use isset check for post value

Comment: Is the name you used in html is nama ?

Comment: Can you add the html code?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
@$sekolah = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['sekolah']);
@$nama = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['nama']);
@$kelas = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['nis']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO sekolah (sekolah, nama, nis) VALUES ('$sekolah', '$nama', '$nis')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Include @ before variables because in localhost you can get undefined index error.

Answer (score 0):

undefined index means that ,in the $_POST array there isn't an index (key) for the keys nama and nis. It would be safer checking to see if the value is set before attempting to access it:

Use `isset($_POST['nama'])`to check for the existence of that variable: